# Opening up Ports on the Nexus One (Version 2.1)

Tags: android, networking, nexus-one

I'm trying to load a web application that needs to connect to port 873. I'm getting an error message that seems to imply that it can't reach that port and I'm guessing that Android 2.1 doesn't expose that port out of the box.

Is there any way to open up ports in the 2.1 operating system?

Thanks in advance,

=Ryan

Comment: I'm not quite sure but this could also be a problem from your provider. If I remember correctly t-mobile is blocking some ports for mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ports lower than 1024, without you rooting the device. That's a Linux thing more than an Android thing.

Comment: Bummer, but that makes sense. Thanks!